# Como usar uma variável do dentro de função em fora de função?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Passado até hoje, sempre errei, continuo não entender nada porque não funcionava. Alguém pode explicar?

Vou usar um exemplo de código:

```
def test(x, y):
    if x == y:
        v1 = False
    else: 
        v1 = True
    return v1
test(3,3)
if v1 == True:
    print("OK")
```

Apareceu assim:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-11958f52b994> in <module>
      6     return v1
      7 test(3,3)
----> 8 if v1 == True:
      9     print("OK")

NameError: name 'v1' is not defined
```

Já tentei usar "return", mas parece que "return" não serve nada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu consegui ajeita o seu codigo assim
Declarei a variavel v1 fora da função, e o return foi direto pra ela

```
v1 = True

def test(x, y):
    if x == y:
        v1 = False
    else:
        v1 = True
    return v1
v1 = test(3,3)
if v1 == True:
    print("OK")
else:
    v1 = False
    print('FALSE')
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa estudar melhor sobre escopo de variáveis ([este artigo](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/), por exemplo).

Sua variável `v1` é criada dentro da função `test`, ou seja, ela só existe dentro desta função.

Quando você faz `return v1` você está retornando **o valor** contido na variável de nome `v1`, depois que a função encerra sua execução **o nome** `v1` "deixa de existir" (você não pode usá-lo pois escopo onde ele é válido é dentro da função em que ele foi criado).

O que você não entendeu ainda do `return` é que o valor retornado pode ser usado quando a função é chamada.

No seu caso você poderia pegar o valor retornado na função e salvar numa variável e fazer a comparação que você deseja.

Exemplo:

```
resultado = test(3, 3)

if resultado:
    print('Números são diferentes.')
else:
    print('Números são iguais.')
```

Note que você pode escolher o nome que quiser para a variável que guardará o resultado retornado pelo função `teste`, não precisa ser `v1`.

Quando você entender melhor como funcionam os escopos de variáveis você também conhecerá os *statements* [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) e [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) que te ajudam a instruir o interpretador sobre o escopo de suas variáveis.